# actually creating a webpage with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

An extremely simple question but I am noob. I have been learning javascript and jquery for a while on jsfiddle, there everything works fine, building cool quizzes and all, but when I tried to actually create a directory, reference the jquery library and my javascript file, nothing works, even the below code, when saved as an HTML file doesn't work. I just paste it into notepad and save it as html, when I open it with it doesn'T work.

```
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>webpage</title>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                window.onload = function() {
                    var myDiv = document.getElementById('#div');
                    myDiv.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Hi my name is Mehmetcan"));
                }
             </script>
       </head>
       <body>
            <div id="myDiv"> </div>
       </body>
   </html>
```

Comment: Remove `#` in this line and correct it with this: var `myDiv = document.getElementById('myDiv');`

Comment: `getElementById('#div')`. Where's the element with the ID `#div`? Works fine if you fix that http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/WF3yY/

Comment: this : `var myDiv = document.getElementById('#div');` should be written `var myDiv = document.getElementById('div');` , note the absence of `#` symbol, which is usefull in jquery selectors, but not when you use `getElementById` which already knows you're passing an id...

Comment: Sounds like you are just serving the HTML file off of disk -- i.e. without a WebServer?  If so you probably will want to reference reference jQuery from a CDN rather than your filesystem.  If you're you're serving the page with a webserver than it is probably fine.

Comment: Note: There's no jQuery here.

Comment: thank you very much, and sorry for the dumb ID mistakes, I am really hungry and stupid at the moment, I had created this quiz on js-fiddle, and I am trying to serve it into an HTML file, without a server, iff of disc, I can't seem to do it. I can reference the jquery library, but my javascript code works on jsfiddle, when I reference it from directory, off of disc, it doesn't work, here is the quiz: http://jsfiddle.net/Mehmetcan/9N542/40/

Answer (score 0):

Use this as starting point:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>

        <title>webpage</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                var myDiv = document.getElementById('myDiv');
                myDiv.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Hi my name is Mehmetcan"));
            });
         </script>
   </head>
   <body>
        <div id="myDiv"> </div>
   </body>
```

Comment: jQuery is not necessary. Also, [`getElementbyID`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementById) does not use the `#` identifier to reference IDs.

Comment: @showdev I know jQuery is not necessary, but the looks like the OP is trying to know how to reference and use jQuery

Answer (score 0):

Another approach that **doesn't** rely on JQuery but on pure, vanilla javascript.

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>webpage</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            document.body.onload = loadSite;
            function loadSite() {
                var newDiv = document.createElement("span");
                var newContent = document.createTextNode("Hi there and greetings!");
                newDiv.appendChild(newContent);
                myDiv.appendChild(newDiv);
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="myDiv"> </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

You can find the full javascript sample as well as more information here, on the [document.createElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.createElement) MDN pages.

```javascript
document.body.onload = addElement;
var my_div = null; 
var newDiv = null; 
function addElement () { 
    // create a new div element 
    // and give it some content 
    var newDiv = document.createElement("div"); 
    var newContent = document.createTextNode("Hi there and greetings!"); 
    newDiv.appendChild(newContent); //add the text node to the newly created div. 
    // add the newly created element and its content into the DOM 
    my_div = document.getElementById("org_div1"); 
    document.body.insertBefore(newDiv, my_div); 
}
```